# Visual Studio 2017 cannot build blank app after disabling/reenabling xaml designer?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, c++-winrt

I am trying rebuild a C++/winrt app by beginning with the BlankApp1 that is created by VS2017 - at first the blankapp built and ran just fine, but then I tried disabling xaml designer using the disable switch in tools/options/xaml (I prefer not to use the designer). However, the original sample xaml files remained, so the sample interface remained. I tried deleting the xaml files, after which nothing would build. Finally I trashed the whole blankapp directory, turned xaml designer back on in VS, restarted VS, and now have tried twice to create and run new BlankApps without changing anything in them. I get build errors: "Cannot open include file 'XamlMetaDataProvider.g.h' (compiling source file GeneratedFiles\XamlTypeInfo.Impl.g.cpp)" Does anyone know what to change in VS to make it functional again? And if I want to disable designer, is it enough to turn it off in options, or do certain files also need changing?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know how to make it build and run, though I haven't yet succeeded in programmatically adding xaml elements as I had done with a previous app. Here's what makes the blankapp compile and run with the xamldesigner disabled: (1) Use the switch in Tools/Options/Xaml to turn off the designer, then restart Visual Studio. (2) Find the mainpage.idl and insert this declaration:

```
 runtimeclass XamlMetaDataProvider : Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IXamlMetadataProvider
    {
        XamlMetaDataProvider();
    };
```

That seems to be the missing step required if the designer gets turned off. I hope someone will correct me if I'm mistaken, but this appears to do the trick.
[Update] In Visual Studio 15.9.0 Preview 3, now with support for xaml designer in C++/winrt apps, I cannot find a way to use the complex and dynamic xaml interface I had created programmatically in the previous VS. I may have to post a new and separate question about this: is it still possible to programmatically add xaml elements?